# validating custom domain for signup form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my company email-id's in sign up form...so that the form accepts only my company mail id...so now whats the problem here is after validating(ie; when we click submit button then we get an alert message)  the form is getting refreshed and the entered values are cleared...so any help or suggestions so that it is not refreshed??thanks in advance...

My Javascript method is:

```
    function submitAlbum() {
    var frm = document.getElementById("frmRegistration");
    //validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value);
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@bdisys.com', email.length - '@bdisys.com'.length) !== -1) {
            //      alert('Submission was successful.');
            var r = confirm("Are You Sure You Want to add your details.");
            if (r == true) {
                frm.action = "signUpServlet?formidentity=doRegistration&checkboxStatus=" + checkboxStatus;
                frm.submit();
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            alert('Email must be a Company e-mail address (your.name@bdisys.com).');
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('email').focus();
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `localStorage` for this.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the job.

```
<input type = "email" pattern ="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@bdisys.com">
```

Check this bin
    http://jsbin.com/dew/5/edit

Comment: @SalmanAmaan any problem with this answer? Why its not up voted or accepted?

Comment: i accepted it already but you edited the answer again so thats the problem!!thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your validation method to the submit event of your form.
Inside the validation method, stop the event to propagate if the field is invalid, or let it bubble if it's ok.

```
var frm = document.getElementById("frmRegistration");
frm.addEventListener('submit', validate, false);
var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;

function validate(event) {
  // validateEmail
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var confirmed = false;
  if (re.test(email)) {
    confirmed = true;
    if (email.indexOf('@bdisys.com', email.length - '@bdisys.com'.length) !== -1) {
      confirmed = confirm("Are You Sure You Want to add your details.");
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('email').focus();
    alert('Email must be a Company e-mail address (your.name@bdisys.com).'); 
  }
  if (!confirmed) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
}
```

I suggest you to use jQuery to make your code simplier and before all portable.

Comment: hi fuegy...can you make the required changes if possible please!!coz am new in javascript.....!!